# processing camera frames as bitmaps at set intervals

Tags: android, image, bitmap, camera, frame

I'm trying to do something very different with my android app: I need to grab the image of the camera as a bitmap at timed intervals (every 2 seconds or so). I don't want it in real time because I need to run several heavy processes on the bitmap once I have it, and for efficiency I don't want to run those dozens of times a second. I also don't need to save it as a file, I just need it in currentBitmap.

This is the code where I try to make it happen:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Camera camera;
private CameraPreview camPreview;
private FrameLayout camLayout;

// The app will process the camera frame on intervals instead of constantly
private static final long PROCESS_TIME = 2000; //(in milliseconds)
private static final long START_TIME = 2000;
private Timer timer;

// I want the bitmap in this instance
private Bitmap currentBitmap;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    camLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

    setupCameraPreview();

    // Set up the timer
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {            
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TimerMethod();
        }
    }, START_TIME, PROCESS_TIME);
}

private void TimerMethod()
{   // Run Timer_Action on the same thread as the UI
    this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Action);
}

private Runnable Timer_Action = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        // Process each bitmap here
        try {

            camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Photo capture attempted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

private Camera.PictureCallback pictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        try {
            currentBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Photo capture successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};


private void setupCameraPreview() {

    try {   // Try to initialize the camera
        camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
        camPreview = new CameraPreview(this, camera);
        camLayout.addView(camPreview);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        camera = null;
        camPreview = null;
    }
}
```

What happens when I run is that the camera preview and timer seem to run fine. But the pictureCallback, data[], and currentBitmap all stay null, so the try blocks throw their exceptions and the app moves on. My guess is that pictureCallback isn't getting data from the camera, but how would I fix that? and if that's not the problem than what is?

All help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why pictureCallback is not initialized properly,  I usually declare this callback as a method of the activity, which *implements* Camera.PictureCallback and/or Camera.PreviewCallback.

But for your purpose, if you can be satisfied with preview resolution, you can setOneShotPreviewCallback by timer, or simply when you complete processing of the previous buffer.

Preview resolution can usually be 640×480, and on contemporary powerful devices up to 1080p.

On most phones and tablets, the callback receives only YUV image, but some may be configured to provide RGB. In any case, yuv to rgb conversion should not be a problem (use the fixed point formulae from Wikipedia).